# Conflict tikz and pgfplots trim axis right

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, incompatibility

I have the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trim axis left, trim axis right}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[] (a) {Node};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There seems to be a conflict between `tikz` and the pgfplots option `trim axis left`, which yields the error message

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named `current axis' is known.
```

I need that setting because of alignment of multiple pgfplots in the document, so a global setting seems the best option.
Is there any known workaround?

Comment: Unrelated: When using PGFPlots, you need to set the `compat` level - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can not be a conflict between TikZ and PGFPlots as PGFPlots is on top of TikZ and always needs it. Apparent there needs to be an `axis` environment to be able to use the options `trim axis left, trim axis right`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{trim axis left, trim axis right}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Empty graph]

**Edit - Code with extra TikZ pictures**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} %TikZ before graph
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{trim axis left, trim axis right} %options for all following axis
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]% Options for this axis
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} %TikZ after graph
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two lines and an empty graph]

Comment: nice, thanks. Problem is that I need in the same document to make a tikz plot which has no axis (just a scheme of something else). any workaround?

Comment: No workaround is needed. You are free to add any number of Tikz pictures.

Comment: but how should I hide the axis then?

Comment: I do not fully follow - let me add an example with TikZ pictures

Comment: ok so you cannot put \pgfplotsset{trim axis left, trim axis right} in the preamble... I had the same problem because the tikz shapes would just not show in the axis environment

Comment: You can, but apparently there will be a problem, if there is no axis in the first TikZ picture(this is also news to me). You can (but do not) put `\node (current axis) {};` in all TikZ pictures to avoid "Error: No shape named `current axis' is known."

Comment: ok thank you, it's weird that it's like this and requires such a workaround (which is indeed a workaround...)